# Replacing jars in tc server

Tags: java, tcserver

I have created two Projects in STS One is common which will be bundles as a jar file in Maven. I have another Project EntWeb which has a depndency on common.jar.
The EntWeb will be generated as war file and will be deployed in tc server.

The problem now is everytime I change some java files in common project I need do a Maven install in EntWeb project. which is taking more time.

Is there a way in tc server I an replace the common jar directly without installing again in EntWeb.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Anand

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not using [WTC](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) to launch your server, and you are working with an "exploded war" configuration (TC server , you can simply replace the jar you created within the "exploded" war directory. After that you will probably need a restart but TC server will identify that the WAR is older than the exploded directory and will not extract the contents of the WAR again.

```
TC Server
 - Instance #1
   - bin
   - conf
   - webapps
     - my_app.war
     - my_app // This is the exploded dir - put the new JAR here under WEB-INF/lib
```